# Can't contact Exchange server on MacBook to get mail outside office network?

Tags: email, osx-lion, exchange

Whenever I'm on some outside wifi and try to access my office mail via Exchange on my MacBook (Lion mail app), I get the following message:

> The server returned the error: The server “mail.XXX.fi” cannot be contacted on port 4434.

and the account stays offline.

With the same settings, I have no problem getting my mail on my iPhone, or on the same MacBook when plugged into the office Ethernet network.

Am running the latest version of Lion and all apps are up to date.

iPhone is configured exactly the same as the laptop. I have read somewhere that Exchange is designed for mobile devices, and Lion might have a problem with it--is this true?

Comment: Your office support people will be better placed to help you find out why this doesn't work.  The iphone is probably differently configured.

Comment: Does this happen on just 1 WIFI network? My only thought could be your firewall configuration on the WAP.